# Flask button redirects falsely to index

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I have an input field that should save the content to a database:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="row">
        {{ comment.content }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<div class="row">
    <form action="." method="POST">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="contents" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="save">
    </form>
</div>
```

in flask_app I check whether it is a POST or GET method. If it is POST it should reload the page with a redirect. However, it always returns me to "home".

```
@app.route('/photography', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_photography():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('photography.html', comments=Comment.query.all())
    elif request.method == "POST":
        comment = Comment(content=request.form["contents"])
        db.sesson.add(comment)
        db.session.commmit()
        return 'welcome to flask!'
    else:
        flash('error message via flash')
```

return 'welcome to flaks' was just a test, it still redirects me to home after clicking the button. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your 'action="."' is the problem. Set it to **url_for('show_photography')** in the template.